# Google Forms validation based on multiple questions

Tags: forms, scripting

I want to create a form that lets people choose items they will get

Each person should get 10 items, and no more than 4 of each item.

So I create 3 questions with multiple choice answers:

Item A: 0 - 4
Item B: 0 - 4
Item C: 0 - 4

Now upon submission, or better yet before, I want to make sure that the values selected in the 3 questions is added up to exactly 10.

Is there a way to do such thing?